# Transforming lots of XMLs (File objects) into a single String with all the files' contents

Tags: java, xml, performance, file-io, memory-management

What is the most effective (performance-wise) and clean way to perform the transformation of taking up to 500 XML files, sized up to 50 Mb each and making a single String out of them. All files are XML and need to keep the formatting etc.

I'm currently doing the reading using XMLEventReader , and then XMLEventWriter,reading one event at a time and using StringBuilder to concatenate all the String results.
Then making it into a String at the end of the method, but this crashes due to lack of Java heap space in the IDE, way before 500 files...

Thanks !

Comment: What are you using the string for afterwards? Maybe there is a more performant way if its possible to skip this intermediate string.

Comment: There's no option to change the output format, as it's being used by something similar to a "client library" which must not be changed. Thank though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This String object will have a size of upto 50 GByte (50 MByte * 500 * 2). You're aware of that, are you?

As you talk about input **files** and want to keep the serialized xml data in a String, you don't have to parse the files but can just append the file contents to your StringBuilder.

Assuming, all files are in a single folder and with a little help of commons-io, this should do it (... not on my machine with 4 GB Ram, btw):

```
 File[] files = parentFolder.list();
 StringBuilder veryVeryBigBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 for (File file: files) {
   if (isXmlFile(file)) {
      veryVeryBigBuilder.append(FileUtils.readFileToString(), encoding);
   }
 }
```

Comment: you mean I should just read the file (as bytes[]?) and append to StringBuilder?

Comment: A `char` in Java is represented by 16 bit and a String is backed by a `char[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to bother about them being XML? Can't you read each file in turn line by line using a `BufferedReader` and just output all the lines to a `PrintWriter`?

Comment: I need to preserver their XMLness, for lack of better word -as this is what the caller method expects...I'll check out the approach you suggested and see whether it works for this case.

Comment: Note that the resulting concatenated file will not be valid XML as it won't have a single root node. However it seems improbable that you would ever use such a large file as XML; parsing it would almost certainly run you out of memory.

Comment: yep, that's indeed the error response the caller method provided. As it indeed parses it as XML.. :(